# Converting MemberExpression to CallExpression

Tags: javascript, node.js, esprima

How do I convert a MemberExpression to CallExpression to run JS to get object key with ESPrima? Here's my input:

```
console.log("test");
```

What I want:

```
console["lo" + "G".toLowerCase()]("test");
```

The `"lo" + "G".toLowerCase()` is coming from an external helper, so my problem is just converting `.log` to an "array" element which can execute JS to get the final key.

If you look into the AST, you can see this:

```
property: Identifier { type: 'Identifier', name: 'log' } },
```

But, I don't know how to convert this to CallExpression. Is this even possible with ESPrima?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `console["lo" + "G".toLowerCase()]("test")` already works as-is in JavaScript. Are you trying to operate directly on the AST or something?

Comment: [Here is a link to the Esprima online parser demo.](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=%20console%5B%22lo%22%20%2B%20%22G%22.toLowerCase()%5D(%22hello%20world%22)%3B%0A) As you can see, there's a "CallExpression" around the "MemberExpression".

Comment: Yes, it works, but, how could I change it automatically? I want a Node.js program to convert `console.log("test");` to `console["log"]("test");` ("log" can be something else, more programmatical).

Comment: This is for an automatic JS obfuscator; I have the "log" string obfuscation part done already, modifying the code is the problem.

Comment: I'm "obfuscating" _normal_ functions (without "parent") like this: `node.callee.name = "global[" + helper.obfuscateName(node.callee.name) + "]";` (`alert("asd")` -> `global[OBFUSCATED_RESULT_HERE]("asd")`)

Comment: Can't you just generate the AST for the obfuscated part and use it as a template, and then plug it into the real AST to replace the "Identifier" clause in the "MemberExpression"?

Comment: Node.js's ESTraverse goes to an endless loop when I do that.

Comment: Then you're probably somehow ending up with a cycle in the object graph. You should post the code you've attempted to use; without that it's kind-of hard to help.

Comment: When ESTraverse detects a node callee with MemberExpression and a node as CallExpression, it does this: `node.callee.property = { type: "CallExpression", callee: esprima.parse(helper.obfuscateName(node.callee.property.name)).body[0] };`